# Writing a function in nodejs, and having it display in the view

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

So I am scraping a website, and I want it to show the data to innerHTML, and I am having trouble getting it to work. I am trying to use

```
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = searchJobs('');
```

But it's telling me that document is not defined, sorry nooby question but It's easier to ask than be stuck on the same thing for 45 minutes.

Here is the code :

```
function searchJobs(i) {
    const url = axios.get('actualurl')
    return fetch(`${url}${i}`)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(res => {
            const jobs = [];
            const jobsBody = [];
            const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);

            $('.result').each((index, element) => {
                const title = $(element).children('.title').text();
                const linkToJob = $(element).children('.title').children('a').attr('href')
                const body = $(element).children('.summary').text();
                jobs[index] = { title, linkToJob, body };
            });

            return jobs;
 
        });
}
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = searchJobs('');
module.exports = searchJobs;
```

I can get the scraper to console.log just fine.

index route :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const scraper = require('../scrapers/scrapers');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

app.js :

```
const express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    logger = require('morgan'),
    puppeteer = require('puppeteer'),
    axios = require('axios'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio');
es6Renderer = require('express-es6-template-engine');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.engine('html', es6Renderer);
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

I think the problem is actually in the view which it's basically just this to keep the post short :

```
<body>
        <p id="results"></p>
        <script src="/scrapers/scrapers.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: There is no `document` object in node.js.  That would only exist in a browser or a browser-like environment (such as cheerio creates which would only be present within that cheerio context).   Also, `searchJobs()` returns a promise which you don't seem to be using properly.  Can you show us where you're trying to use the `searchJobs()` function and describe exactly what you're trying to accomplish with it?  Are you trying to insert jobs data into a page that your web server is rendering?  If so, which route?

Comment: When you say you can get the scrapper to console.log just fine do you mean log in the server or the browser?

Comment: @ajaybee I get it to log in the console lol.. like I can return jobs, and then console.log(searchJobs())

Comment: Which console? node applications can console.log to the server console. Browser JavaScript will console.log to the browser developer console

Comment: @ajaybee my server terminal I'm assuming not in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to accomplish. Remove the `document.getElementById` line from scrapers.js and modify the others like so:

index route:

```js
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { locals: { results: scraper.searchJobs() }});
});
```

view:

```html
<body>
  <p id="results">${results}</p>
</body>
```

By doing this you're running the scraper on the server inside of node and then using the templating engine to render the results into the HTML prior to sending it down to the browser.

Comment: Thank you for the help, now I am getting a new error, not sure if on the right track or not, It's telling me " Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "./views "

Comment: It’s looking for an error.html file in your views directory

Comment: sorry that was obvious, I the errors are super confusing whenever using like express, and node and all this I've just got into the habit of checking model>routes>views for errors instead of actually paying attention to the error.. sometimes.

Comment: now. It's telling me searchJobs is not a function.. even though I am requiring "../scrappers/scrappers" which has the function in it.

Comment: You’re exporting searchJobs as scrapper so just call `scrapper()`

Comment: awesome thank you, now I have to get it not show as a promise object!

Comment: `scrapper().then(result => res.render(‘index’, {locals: { results }});`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209528/discussion-between-blue-and-ajaybee).

Comment: Going to mark your answer as the answer, because you have helped me get passed the error onto new ones lol.